# Display image in imageView from Json byte[] value, SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to convert `byte[]` into image. The `byte[]` comes from JSON and it's in this format:

Byte array value for json :

```
"255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,255,219,0,132,0,9,6,7,20,19,18,20,20,19,20,21,22,20,22,20,21,...".
```

I'm using the following code convert `byte[]` to bitmap image.

```
            String encodedString="255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0....";
            byte[] encodeByte = encodedString.getBytes();
            System.out.println("encodeByte : "+encodeByte);
            System.out.println("encodeByte.length : "+encodeByte.length);
            Bitmap photo=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0,                     encodeByte.length);
            System.out.println("Bitmap photo : "+photo);
            btnImg.setImageBitmap(photo);
```

I'm getting the following error in Logcat:

```
10-31 00:20:57.210: I/System.out(1315): encodeByte : [B@b3d249d8
10-31 00:20:57.210: I/System.out(1315): encodeByte.length : 18320
10-31 00:20:57.220: D/skia(1315): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-31 00:20:57.220: I/System.out(1315): Bitmap photo : null
```

I got error like this.please help me out

Answer (score 0):

This is how you convert a byteArray to Base64Encoded String and convert it to bitmap image.

Use the folllowing code to convert byte[] to bitmap image.

//convert byteArray to base64 String

```
            byte[] photo_byte = (your byte[] from json response);
            //To encode byte[] as string for other purpose
            String photoString =Base64.encodeToString(photo_byte, Base64.DEFAULT);

            //decode the string to bitmap 
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(photoString, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decoded_photo_byte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

Comment: using this code i'm getting same error.   10-31 01:49:05.040: D/skia(1575): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-31 01:49:05.040: I/System.out(1575): Bitmap photo : null